# why $.ajax is not getting data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to validate form and then send the values using $.ajax .but it shows  Undefined index: **is_ajax**. why it does not get form_data? why it happens?What change should be done?
here is my script

```
function validateForm()
{

     var oldPassword = document.forms["dsettings"]["oldPassword"].value;
     var newPassword = document.forms["dsettings"]["newPassword"].value;
     var retypePassword = document.forms["dsettings"]["retypePassword"].value;


        if (document.forms["dsettings"]["oldPassword"].value == null || oldPassword == "") {
        alert("Enter old password");
        return false;
    }

    else if (document.forms["dsettings"]["newPassword"].value == null || newPassword == "") {
        alert("Enter new password");
        return false;
    }

    else if (document.forms["dsettings"]["retypePassword"].value == null || retypePassword == "") {
        alert("Retype new password");
        return false;
    }

    else if ( newPassword != retypePassword) {
        alert("Retype new password correctly");
        return false;
    }

    else
        {
            var action = $("#dsettings").attr('action');
            var form_data = {
                    oldPassword: $('#oldPassword').val(),
                    newPassword: $('#newPassword').val(),

                    is_ajax: 1
                                };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: form_data,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response == "success")
                            $("#message").html('<p class="success">Successfully changed password!</p>');

                    else if(response == "wrong_old_password")
                        {   
                            $("#message").html('<p class="error">Wrong old password!type again!</p>');
                        }       
                    else
                        {   
                            $("#message").html('<div class="error">update error.Try again! !</div>');
                        }   
                }
            });

        }

}
```

my html code

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  onclick="return validateForm()" class="form-submit" >submit</button>
```

and php code

```
<?php $is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
// some codes ?>
```

Comment: does other fields appear correctly? why don't you try `$_POST` ?

Comment: i use $_POST same things happen. it happens for all the values

Comment: check the console in the firefox is it post the data to the page???

Comment: i want to find out the error in my code.I dont know how to check console :(

Comment: add a `return false;` at the end of validateForm()

Comment: Can you paste entire code (including html containing form), that will help debug the issue.

Comment: the entire code is more than 1000 characters.how can i send u?

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems to be your very first post and very ugly , you need to clean it something like this (which is not perfect either !)

Provide as much as data as possible e. g

**HTML**

```
<form action="fakeurl.com" method="post" name="dsettings" id="dsettings" >
   <ul>
       <li>Old Password: <input type="password" name="oldPassword" /></li>
       <li>New Password: <input type="password" name="newPassword" /></li>
       <li>Retype New Password: <input type="password" name="retypePassword" /></li>
       <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password" /></li>
       <li><div id="message"/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dsettings').on('submit',function(event){
        changePassword(this)
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
function validateChangePassword(frm){
    var oldPassword=frm["oldPassword"].value
    var newPassword=frm["newPassword"].value
    var retypePassword =frm["retypePassword"].value;

    if (oldPassword.trim()=="") {
        $('#message').html("<p class='error'>Enter old password</p>");
        return false;
    }
    else if (newPassword.trim()=='') {
        $('#message').html("<p class='error'>Enter new password</p>");
        return false;
    }
    else if (retypePassword.trim() == "") {
        $('#message').html("<p class='error'>Retype new password</p>");
        return false;
    }
    else if ( newPassword != retypePassword) {
        $('#message').html("<p class='error'>Retype new password correctly</p>");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}   


function changePassword(frm){
  if(validateChangePassword(frm)){
    var url = $(frm).attr('action');
    var data = {
            oldPassword: $(frm).find('input[name="oldPassword"]').val(),
            newPassword: $(frm).find('input[name="newPassword"]').val(),
            retypePassword: $(frm).find('input[name="retypePassword"]').val(),
            is_ajax: 1
           };
    ajaxPost(url,data);
  }
  return false;
}

function ajaxPost(post_url,post_data){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data: post_data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response == "success")
                    $("#message")
                    .html('<p class="success">Successfully changed password!</p>');
            else if(response == "wrong_old_password")
                {   
                    $("#message")
                    .html('<p class="error">Wrong old password!type again!</p>');
                }       
            else
                {   
                    $("#message")
                    .html('<div class="error">update error.Try again! !</div>');
                }   
        }
    });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r6udveob/)

**Possible Issues**

- Avoid using custom js and jquery mix
  I suspect you provided any id to element e.g $('#oldPassword').val()
- There is good plugin for form [validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) use that one

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code on function call with parameter:

`function validateForm(e) {
e.preventDefault();`

and here:

`<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  onclick="validateForm(this); return false;" class="form-submit" >submit</button>`

Comment: change to `onclick="validateForm(this); return false;"` this call must ALWAYS return false

Comment: now it does not check the values.directly show the error

Comment: did you change like I asked? or you just removed `validateForm(this)` call ?? do you have public url to see your page?

Comment: i replace onclick="return validateForm(this)" by onclick="validateForm(this); return false;"

Comment: hmmm try to change here `<button type="button"` but that is very weird... it mustn't be as you try to say....

Comment: so you want to say, that onclick event doesn't work for button?

Comment: how can i send you the whole code?may you check the whole?

Comment: there is no whole code. there is a button with onclick called function. and you say that onclick doesn't work. just create new `<button type="button" onclick="alert('new button');" >click to check</button>` and click? if alert works replace alert with your `<button type="button" onclick="validateForm(this);" >click to check</button>`  that MUST work in any universe :-)

Comment: very very very much thanks. finally it works. thank you kim for your help :)

Comment: You are very welcome :-) So did you get the problem you had? you did POST twice, one in your js function, and after that your submit button continued execution as regular html form and sent you to the `action` page as declared for the `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery-1.4.3.min.js file before **validateForm** function call.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Change Password" onclick="validateForm()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answers you've given in the comments, what's almost certainly happening is that:

- You are not preventing the default submit behavior, so the default submit behavior is taking place
- There is an error somewhere in your code that is causing your `validateForm()` function to fail and for your `$.ajax` to never run

To troubleshoot this:

- Change your button to `type="button"`.
- Open up your JS console (you can usually do this by pressing F12 and clicking the Console tab)
- See if there are any errors in the console.

Once you figure out what the error is, you should:

- Stop using `onclick` handlers and unobtrusively set up events
- Use `preventDefault()` to prevent default submit events

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validateForm();
    });
});
```